# Spring DM, Rest, JAXB Integration issue

Tags: spring-mvc, osgi

I am using Spring Rest with Spring DM (OSGi). I need to use JAXB for Marshalling/Unmarshalling .I can easily use JAXB with Spring when the Model object is of the same project. I, however, run into issues when I try to do the same thing in OSGi (Spring DM). Because I keep the Model Object into different bundle, `jaxb2Marshaller` is not able to find the Model with annotation `@XmlRootElement`.

Exception is:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 51 in XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/building-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 51; columnNumber: 52;
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no
>   declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'

Please suggest me some workaround to achieve this.

Comment: Did you define the namespace and schema for tx?

Comment: Yes, I did do that. I have a Spring DM prototype with Spring enabled Rest controllers. I use Spring OXM for Marshalling/Un-marshalling and configure my model objects like this: <bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="com.smartpants.artwork.controllers.MyJaxb2Marshaller"> <property name="classesToBeBound"> <list> <value>com.smartpants.artwork.domain.Person</value> <value>com.smartpants.artwork.domain.People</value> </list> </property> </bean> it works perfectly fine.But, it does not work with OSGi bundles. I keep my Controller in one bundle and Model object in another bundle and this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just happened to revisit this post of mine. This issue was resolved long back. I used Spring’s ‘Out Of The Box’ JAXB Marshaller (org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller) that does Marshalling and Un-marshalling for us. Sorry for my late reply and thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

This might well be related to the fact that jaxb is also provided by the system bundle due to the jre containing jaxb. Make sure you import a special version of it and also make sure this version is installed. This probably will help you on this. You might also need to make sure the version exported by the system bundle is configured the right way. For this you need to alter the jre.properties in the etc folder and set the right version to the jaxb packages.